# How to add another List of item for DropDownMenu, and then use the items in widget

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu

So I'm trying to make a drop down menu for each options and insert a different List of items each. First of all, because my Dropdownmenu widget shares the same properties for one and another, I extracted the widget to another class name "MenuDropDown". **Here is the code for the widget.**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'List.dart';

class MenuDropDown extends StatefulWidget {
  final String dropdownText;
  final List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> itemList;
  MenuDropDown({this.dropdownText, this.itemList});
  @override
  _MenuDropDownState createState() => _MenuDropDownState();
}

class _MenuDropDownState extends State<MenuDropDown> {
  String selectedItem;

  List<DropdownMenuItem> getGroomingTypeList() {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> dropdownItems = [];
    for (String groomingType in groomingTypeList) {
      var newItem = DropdownMenuItem(
        child: Text(groomingType),
        value: groomingType,
      );
      dropdownItems.add(newItem);
    }
    return dropdownItems;
  }

  List<DropdownMenuItem> getCatBreedsList() {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> dropdownItems = [];
    for (String catBreed in catBreedsList) {
      var newItem = DropdownMenuItem(
        child: Text(catBreed),
        value: catBreed,
      );
      dropdownItems.add(newItem);
    }
    return dropdownItems;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8.0, 0, 10.0),
      child: Container(
        width: 325.0,
        height: 50.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black45,
              offset: Offset(2.5, 5.5),
              blurRadius: 5.0,
            )
          ],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: DropdownButton(
              value: selectedItem,
              hint: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(22.0, 0, 0, 0),
                child: Text(
                  widget.dropdownText,
                  style: TextStyle(),
                ),
              ),
              items: widget.itemList,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedItem = value;
                });
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

above here I created a method to get the list item from the list class that I already created, First it works if I hardcoded the method into the Dropdownmenu's items properties to show the item list, but because I need to use the different list for the different widget, so I think if I try to create a variable of List named itemList, so I can access it from the other class where I can call just the customized variable.

**And this is the Stateful widget where i use my Extracted Dropdownmenu widget :**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'TitleName.dart';
import 'dropdownmenu.dart';

class InformationDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InformationDetailState createState() => _InformationDetailState();
}

class _InformationDetailState extends State<InformationDetail> {
  MenuDropDown _menuDropDown = MenuDropDown();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25.0, 68.0, 70.0, 26.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Information Detail',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35.0),
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                // Wrap Column
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TitleName(
                        titleText: 'Grooming Type',
                        infoIcon: Icons.info,
                      ),
                      MenuDropDown(
                        dropdownText: 'Grooming Type...',
                      //I'm trying to implement the list here with a custom variable that contain 
                        a method with different list in dropdownmenu class
                      itemlist: getGroomingTypeList(),
                      ),
                      TitleName(
                        titleText: 'Cat Breeds',
                      ),
                      MenuDropDown(
                        dropdownText: 'Cat Breeds...',
                      ),
                      TitleName(
                        titleText: 'Cat Size',
                        infoIcon: Icons.info,
                      ),
                      MenuDropDown(
                        dropdownText: 'Cat Size...',
                      ),
                      TitleName(
                        titleText: 'Add-On Services',
                      ),
                      MenuDropDown(
                        dropdownText: 'Add - On Services...',
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 15.0, 0, 0),
                        width: 75.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                        ),
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context)
                                .pushNamed('/ReservationDetail');
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**And this is the list that I want to use for each of dropdown menu widget**

```
const List groomingTypeList = ['Basic Grooming', 'Full Grooming'];

const List catBreedsList = [
  'Persia',
  'Anggora',
  'Domestic',
  'Maine Coon',
  'Russian Blue',
  'Slamese',
  'Munchkin',
  'Ragdoll',
  'Scottish Fold',
];

const List catSizeList = [
  'Small Size',
  'Medium Size',
  'Large Size',
  'Extra Large Size',
];

const List addOnServicesList = [
  'Spa & Massage',
  'Shaving Hair / Styling',
  'Injection Vitamis Skin & Coat',
  'Cleaning Pet House and Environment',
  'Fur Tangled Treatment',
];
```

I got stuck from there. How to use a different list for each dropdown menu widget that I made, because I already tried to make a constructor, variable, and method so I can use it separately, but instead I got an error that says,

*type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem>'*

I think I implemented it in the wrong way in the first place. I really need help with another solution to these problems. thank you, everyone!

Comment: The list you mentioned are they static or change dynamically

Comment: they are static list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check out the code that I have made some changes :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(InformationDetail());

class InformationDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InformationDetailState createState() => _InformationDetailState();
}

class _InformationDetailState extends State<InformationDetail> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25.0, 68.0, 70.0, 26.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Information Detail',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35.0),
                  ),
                ),
                Column(
                  // Wrap Column
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          'Grooming Type',
                        ),
                        MenuDropDown(
                          dropdownText: 'Grooming Type...',
                          //I'm trying to implement the list here with a custom variable that contain
                          // a method with different list in dropdownmenu class
                          type: "groomingType",
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Cat Breeds',
                        ),
                        MenuDropDown(
                          dropdownText: 'Cat Breeds...',
                          type: "catBreeds",
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Cat Size',
                        ),
                        MenuDropDown(
                          dropdownText: 'Cat Size...',
                          type: "catSize",
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Add-On Services',
                        ),
                        MenuDropDown(
                          dropdownText: 'Add - On Services...',
                          type: "addOnServices",
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 15.0, 0, 0),
                          width: 75.0,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                          ),
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context)
                                  .pushNamed('/ReservationDetail');
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MenuDropDown extends StatefulWidget {
  final String dropdownText;
  final String type;
  MenuDropDown({this.dropdownText, this.type});
  @override
  _MenuDropDownState createState() => _MenuDropDownState();
}

class _MenuDropDownState extends State<MenuDropDown> {
  String selectedItem;
  List<String> dropdownItems = [];

  List<String> groomingTypeList = ['Basic Grooming', 'Full Grooming'];

  List<String> catBreedsList = [
    'Persia',
    'Anggora',
    'Domestic',
    'Maine Coon',
    'Russian Blue',
    'Slamese',
    'Munchkin',
    'Ragdoll',
    'Scottish Fold',
  ];

  List<String> catSizeList = [
    'Small Size',
    'Medium Size',
    'Large Size',
    'Extra Large Size',
  ];

  List<String> addOnServicesList = [
    'Spa & Massage',
    'Shaving Hair / Styling',
    'Injection Vitamis Skin & Coat',
    'Cleaning Pet House and Environment',
    'Fur Tangled Treatment',
  ];

  List<String> getListBasedOnName(String value) {
    print(value);
    switch (value) {
      case "groomingType":
        return groomingTypeList;

        break;
      case "catBreeds":
        return catBreedsList;
        break;

      case "catSize":
        return catSizeList;
        break;
      case "addOnServices":
        return addOnServicesList;
        break;
    }

    return null;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print(widget.type);

    dropdownItems = getListBasedOnName(widget.type);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8.0, 0, 10.0),
      child: Container(
        width: 325.0,
        height: 50.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black45,
              offset: Offset(2.5, 5.5),
              blurRadius: 5.0,
            )
          ],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: DropdownButton(
              value: selectedItem,
              hint: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(22.0, 0, 0, 0),
                child: Text(
                  widget.dropdownText,
                  style: TextStyle(),
                ),
              ),
              items: dropdownItems.map((String value) {
                return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: new Text(value),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedItem = value;
                });
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As some of the widgets were missing, I have added mine you can change as per your needs. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Ok i will try to implement your code. Can you explain what went wrong with my code? because i can't figure it out. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: So far what i think is you cannot use the child class methods in the parent class which might not execute it will just say not defined. This is just an observation the things that you are doing within the method might not be correct( just an assumption did not get the error that you mentioned).

Comment: Alright then, thank you so much for the help! it really helpful Sagar!

Comment: Welcome just make an upvote so that it would be helpful for others as well.